# How to use async/await with useEffect React hook, i tried a lot of examples and nothing is working

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks

I need to implement async/await with useEffect React hook. I tried a lot of ways. Every time i have an error: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { ActivityIndicator, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import * as Keychain from 'react-native-keychain'
import useEffectAsync from '../utils'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
})

const AuthLoadingScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await Keychain.getGenericPassword()
      console.log('data', data)
      navigation.navigate(data ? 'App' : 'Auth')
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  const { container } = styles
  return (
    <View style={container}>
      <ActivityIndicator />
      <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
    </View>
  )
}

export { AuthLoadingScreen }
```

Comment: This looks like it should work! What error do you get?

Comment: Try exporting your component while defining like this - `export const AuthLoadingScreen`

Comment: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.

Comment: What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks good, but try this also,

```
export const AuthLoadingScreen = ({ navigation }) => {...}
```

Or

```
const AuthLoadingScreen = ({ navigation }) => {...}

export default AuthLoadingScreen;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Your decision has worked for me! But why its different behavior if i export by not default it is not working?

Comment: This is wrong - `export { AuthLoadingScreen }` you cannot export component like this, component either exported `default` or `named`.

Comment: But how about spaghetti code when you need to import many components from the one folder?

Comment: For that you should do this - `export const combinedComponents = { component1, component2,....}`

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap it in an anonymous function and have it called immediately:

## I might try this:

```
const AuthLoadingScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
   (async () => {
      const data = await Keychain.getGenericPassword()
      console.log('data', data)
      navigation.navigate(data ? 'App' : 'Auth')
    })()

  }, [])

  const { container } = styles
  return (
    <View style={container}>
      <ActivityIndicator />
      <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
    </View>
  )
}
```

If it worked, do let me know because I am learning React Hooks as well :D.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, but the deal was in the right export. My decision has worked only with export default AuthLoadingScreen

Comment: @jocoders thanks a lot for the feedback. As I am also learning hooks, it was really helpful knowing the correct solution.